# Space complexity of recursive function (Time & Space)

Tags: c, algorithm, time-complexity, space-complexity

There is recursion function below, and I did not calculated time & space complexity. I looked at some resources, but it was not clear enough for me the understanding. Could anyone explain the way of solving in the simplest way, and answers the question?

By the way, I tried to solve time complexity, and I found O(2^n). Is it correct?

```
int func(int n) { 
     if (n < 3)
         return 3;
     else {
         return func(n-3)*func(n-3);
     }
}
```

Comment: Interestingly, replacing `return func(x-3)*func(x-3)` by `z= func(x-3); return z*z;` lowers the complexity to O(n) while keeping the same result.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, the time complexity is indeed `O(2 ^ n)`.

The recurrence relation for time complexity is:
`T(n) = 2 * T(n - 3)`

Applying the above equation `k` times:
`T(n) = 2 * 2 * 2 ... k times * T(n - 3 * k) = 2 ^ k * T(n - 3k)`

When `k` is `n/3`, `T(n) = 2 ^ k = 2 ^ (n / 3) = O(2 ^ n)`

There's only one function running at a time and stack depth can be `k` at max.
So, space complexity is `n / 3` or `O(n)`